# Which unit does JTS LineString.getLength() use

Tags: java, jts

I'm trying to figure out which unit JTS LineString.getLength() return.

for example:

```
LineString foo = (initialize line string somehow)
foo.getLength() -> 7.025667228118838E-4
```

Are these Kilometers?, Meters?, Feet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in degrees.

Answer (score 5):

It depends in which unit your coordinate geometries are expressed. If your coordinates are in meters, the perimeter will also be in meters.

Comment: thx! and so if you have coordinates in lat/long then you have an angle . but what is the good way to convert this angle to meters? (better than geom.getLength* (math.Pi/180) * 6378137)

Comment: the best way is to project your geometry to have coordinates in meters and then compute the length. For geometry projection, you might use geotools: See http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/geometry/geometrycrs.html

Answer (score -4):

com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry.getLength() returns a length/perimeter in meters.
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry.getArea() returns an area in squaremeters.

Comment: Wrong: it depends on the SRS set for the geometry, see above! :)